# Is there a world map for the Mortal Engines movie?

Tags: mortal-engines

Just watched the movie a few days ago and I wonder is there a map of some kind showing the world as it is now? (From the books or the actual movie.)

We do see a lot of different maps in the movie itself, but I'm interested in a map of the entire world that is set in the age of the *Mortal Engines*.

Only thing I was able to find comes from [here.](https://mortalengines.fandom.com/wiki/Great_Hunting_Ground)

Comment: Movie or books? Or would you be interested in either?

Comment: Either map would suffice. i get a feeling that the movie veered off a bit from the books, but dont they always...

Comment: I haven't watched the movie, so can't say. Just wondered if you really wanted to be so restrictive in the question - I suspect there's more material about the books than the movie.

Comment: There is an artist on DeviantArt who specializes in maps who has made one or two world maps of their own based on the books https://www.deviantart.com/lowtuff/art/The-World-of-Mortal-Engines-260123935 and https://www.deviantart.com/lowtuff/art/The-World-of-Mortal-Engines-Map-2-316686044 Not posting as an answer as it's not official/canon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several "world maps" seen in the Mortal Engines film.

This from near the Command Centre

[image]

and this found inside the London Museum

[image]

This map was used in some of the pre-visualisation materials (for marketing).

[image]